# Mouse drag sends keystoke (keycode 54, keysym character "c") in X

Tags: linux, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, clipboard, keyboard-events

This is driving me nuts.. some time yesterday I started to see "c" being pressed occasionally on window switches. If I click on a term window, a "c" sometimes show up on it. after reinstalling everything, even on a clean machine, I finally realized it's with mouse drags.

To reproduce, I fire up a xev window and drag the window title, and I get this:

```
FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

ConfigureNotify event, serial 38, synthetic YES, window 0x2400001,
    event 0x2400001, window 0x2400001, (1087,844), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 2, above 0x0, override NO

ConfigureNotify event, serial 38, synthetic YES, window 0x2400001,
    event 0x2400001, window 0x2400001, (1091,844), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 2, above 0x0, override NO

...(more ConfigureNotify events)

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  79  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x4f, subw 0x0, time 64748101, (65,-12), root:(1164,834),
    state 0x10, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x4f, subw 0x0, time 64748101, (65,-12), root:(1164,834),
    state 0x10, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I don't see it consistently if I do it very quickly, but if I drag at 2 seconds intervals, "c" is sent to the window every time.

More context:
1. I am connecting to the desktop via tigervnc, but I tried multiple versions and configs, no difference. It used to work perfectly.
2. Mate or XFCE doesn't matter. I used a new clean machine to install from scratch, no difference.
3. some dot files got synced between my new and old machines for sure. But I think I bisected everything, no config file turned out to affect the behaviour.

I think it's some recent update to one of the X packages, that messes up mouse drags generally, or something to do with the PRIMARY clipboard.. But I'm not sure..

Thank you in advance for any suggestions! Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if its a hardware issue. Try a different mouse and/or keyboard?

Comment: @jamieguinan on the server side, I tried two machines. on the client side I used different keyboards and trackpads. so no, I don't think it's a hardware issue. :(

Comment: The symptom is gone magically.. I guess some component fixed itself by upgrading (my company controls yum upgrades on all these machines.)

Comment: how did you fix it? my left control key is making my life hell :(

Comment: What did you do for this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: It went away by itself, see my previous comment.